# Laravel 5.2:create and edit function

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 ..
There is a `user` and a `profile` table,it is a one-to-one relationship between them,
in `ProfileController`,
after user login,
when access `create` function,
if user's profile has not been created,return `create` page,
else,
redirect to `edit` function.

Question:
How to write the `create` function and `edit` function?
I writed a part of them.
1、how to write the parameter `id` in `create` function?
2、how to find the profile of the login user in `edit` function?

ProfileController:

```
    public function create()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        if (!$user->profile) {
            return view('profile.create');
        }else{
           //how to write 'id'
           return redirect()->action('ProfileController@edit', ['id' => .......]);
        }
    }

    public function edit()
    {
       //how to find the profile of the login user?


       return view('profile.edit', compact('profile'));
    }
```

Comment: I’d instead create the corresponding profile record on `User::create()`: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events

Comment: @MartinBean I don't understand,an example is better.

Comment: @sunshine I pointed you to the documentation, which has examples.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $user = \Auth::user();

    if(isset($user->profile)) {
        return redirect()->action('ProfileController@edit', ['id' => $user->id]);
    }

    return view('profile.create');
}

// Get the current user
public function edit(App\User $user)
{
    if($user->id === \Auth::user()->id) {
        $profile = \Auth::user()->profile;

        return view('profile.edit', compact('profile'));
    }
}
```

Comment: `edit(App\User $user)` you dont pass an instance you pass just an ID `['id' => $user->id]`

Comment: @Froxz This is using route model binding in 5.2.

Comment: Ok got it) I'm still with 5.1))

Comment: There is an error:```Missing required parameters for [Route: api.profile.edit] [URI: api/profile/{profile}/edit].```

Comment: Yep you need to pass the user ID in the url.

Comment: Case like this:There is a button,```<a class="btn btn-primary" href="profile/create" role="button">Create profile</a>```,this is create-url,  after click it,if  profile is already existing,redirect to edit-url  `href="profile/{id}/edit"`,how to make edit-url in controller?

Comment: @chris you might want to add better typehinting: `App/User` that's not a namespace ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = \Auth::user();
```

Same as you have in  `public function create()`
variable `$user` will contain info about current user

More you can create a constructor method like

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
protected $user;
public function __construct(Authenticatable $user){
   // $user is an instance of the authenticated user...
   $this->middleware('auth');
   $this->user = $user;
}
public function edit(){
   $user = $this->user;
}
```

Read [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication)